# Wrap column headers in tableGrob in gridExtra R

Tags: r, plot, graphics, word-wrap, gridextra

I am creating an R output, which includes 2 `ggplot` graphs, and a `tableGrob`.

I am able to insert the table, however the column names are rather long, and so the whole table does not fit in the resulting document.

I would like to wrap the text for column headers only, or alternatively, specific the size of each column

Some code:

```
library(gridExtra)
ref=c("1234567890", "0987654321")
method=c("type 1", "type 2")
methodref=c("ABC", "DEF")
firstdos=c(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-02-01 00:00:00"))
lastdos=c(as.POSIXct("2015-01-31 23:45:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-02-28 23:45:00"))
dur=c("31d 0H 0M 0S", "28d 0H 0M 0S")
maxheart=c("90.25", "96")
minheart=c("40.1", "55.3")
meanheart=c("70.5", "69.4")
maxpre=c("85.6", "89.2")
minpre=c("51", "53.2")
meanpre=c("63.8", "71.1")

DF=data.frame(ref,method,methodref,firstdos,dur,lastdos,maxheart,minheart,meanheart,maxpre,minpre,meanpre)

colnames(DF)=c("Reference","Method Name","Method Reference","First Dosage taken","Duration of Medication","Final Dosage taken",
  "Maximum Heartrate (bpm)","Minimum Heartrate (bpm)","Mean Heartrate (bpm)","Maximum heartrate before trial (bpm)",
  "Minimum heartrate before trial (bpm)","Mean heartrate before trial (bpm)")

g5 <- tableGrob(head(DF))
grid.arrange(g5, nrow=1)
```

In addition (which I know might be worth asking as a separate question), I am currently formatting my `grid.arrange` command using `nrow=3` (2 plots and 1 table). I would like the table to sit across the top of the whole plot, with the second row being the two plots side by side. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
cols <- c("Reference","Method Name","Method Reference","First Dosage taken","Duration of Medication","Final Dosage taken",
               "Maximum Heartrate (bpm)","Minimum Heartrate (bpm)","Mean Heartrate (bpm)","Maximum heartrate before trial (bpm)",
               "Minimum heartrate before trial (bpm)","Mean heartrate before trial (bpm)")

colnames(DF) <- sapply(cols, function(x) paste(strwrap(x, width = 10),  collapse="\n"))

g5 <- tableGrob(head(DF))
grid.arrange(g5, ggplot(), ggplot(), 
             layout_matrix=matrix(c(1,1,2,3), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: You can also add `\n` into the `colnames` values if you want breaks at a specific point.  e.g., `cols <- c("Method\nName")`